# Anychart tagCloud scale

Tags: javascript, html, charts, anychart, tag-cloud

I'm developing a simple website in HTML and I need to add a tagCloud chart. I can't understand how to set the scale method. In the documentation it is explained to use anychart.scales.log() but I need a chart where you can see if a unit has a higher frequency, but at the same time I need that the units with the lower frequencies are not invisible. The logarithmic method puts all the data almost at the same size in my case.

```js
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

      var data = [
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 10000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 100, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 5000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 8000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Phone"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 10000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 100, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 5000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Phone"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 10000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 100, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 5000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 8000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Phone"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 10000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 5000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Technology"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 4000, category: "Seller"},
        {"x": "CompanyNameLTD", "value": 1000, category: "Phone"}
      ];

      var chart = anychart.tagCloud(data);
      
      var tooltip = chart.tooltip();
      
      chart.tooltip().useHtml(true);
      
      tooltip.positionMode("point");
      
      tooltip.format("Goal: <b>{%value}");
      
      chart.angles([0])
      
      chart.container("wordCloudChart");
      
      chart.listen("pointClick", function(e){
         var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + e.point.get("x");
         window.open(url, "_blank");
      });

      chart.background().fill({
      keys: ["#2a2a2a", "#2a2a2a", "#2a2a2a"],
      angle: 130,
      });

      chart.scale(anychart.scales.log());

      chart.draw();
    });
```

And this is the with and without

[image: With]

[image: Without]

Does anyone know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For the data you provided we recommend using the default linear scale (simply not apply the log scale). The log scale is suitable when max value is greater than min by x1000 or even more.
Your data range is between 100 and 10 000, in this case log scale compresses the data range to much.

Comment: So you suggest something like that?

    chart.scale(anychart.scales.linear());

or I need to set something different? Thanks.

Comment: No, simply remove the line `chart.scale(anychart.scales.log());` from your code and that's it. it will apply a linear scale as a default one.

Comment: Are there any other cases? Maybe the data range can change

Comment: If you expect that new data can be more suitable for log scale, you can check the incoming data range and switch the scale type on the fly.